# Openlayers - How to get rendered symbol list with declutter option?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I added the vector layer with "declutter" option in OpenLayers v5.
Source feature was 500 (five hundred) and rendered result is almost 50 (fifty).
After render, I wanna get only fifty rendered list from layer instance.
I know that "forEachFeatureAtPixel" API, but it can capture only a single pixel point.

Any way to get this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getFeaturesInExtent` on `Source` to get features placed in specific area. But there's no way to get only visible features with `declutter` option for now. You may need to request the new method to the OpenLayers team.

Comment: I reviewed OpenLayers codes, but I couldn't find any clue at all.
Thanks for your good feedback. :)